# How to match a string within a .each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given:

```
var countries = ["Afghanistan", "United Kingdom", "Albania", "United Arab Emirates"];
var regex = new RegExp(countries.join("|"), "i");

$wikiDOM.find(".infobox td div li a").each(function(){
  var newtext = $(this).text();
  //console.log(newtext);
  console.log(newtext.match(regex));
});
```

if I do:

```
console.log(newtext);
```

I get:

```
White
Asian
Black
Mixed
Arab
1]
United Kingdom
England and Wales
^
Legislative Grand Committee
```

So we do have a match for `United Kingdom` yet when I run `console.log(newtext.match(regex));` the console gives me `null null null...`

I am looking for a match of a string against the strings in the array and if there is a match, output that match in the console. In this case it'd be `United Kingdom`

Here it is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/825/)

Comment: What output are you looking for?

Comment: @mkaatman I am looking for the console to give me `United Kingdom` as that is the correct match

Comment: I have no idea what your asking here?

Comment: @Liam I am looking for a match of a string against the strings in the array and if there is a match, output that match in the console

Comment: why the down votes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search for a string inside an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424488/how-to-search-for-a-string-inside-an-array-of-strings)

Comment: @Liam i was actually looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13509693/1018804 but I don't understand why the code above isn't working tho, now trying the solution found on that link here

Comment: @Liam  `$wikiDOM.find(".infobox td div li a").each(function(){
         var newtext = $(this).text();
          for( var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++ ) {
            if ( countries[i] === newtext ) {
              console.log(newtext);
            }
          }
        });` but i get nothing in console, if i output countries which is the countries array, i get them all

Comment: @Liam provided my own answer

Comment: @mkaatman provided my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list i was getting via the `.each()` was indeed giving me United Kingdom which we have in the array, yet the html was `United&nbsp;Kingdom` therefore I did:

```
$wikiDOM.find(".infobox td div li a").each(function(){
  var newtext = $(this).html();
  var newtextStriped = newtext.replace(/&nbsp;/g,' ');
  if( $.inArray(newtextStriped, countries) != -1){
    console.log(newtextStriped);
  }
});
```